# Win32 alternative to pthread

Tags: c++, winapi, pthreads, win32-process

Is it possible to write this using the standard win32 CreateMutex style code. I am just wondering if I want to introduce a new library to our application or if I can find a way to write this myself. I just can't figure out how to to the wait inside a CriticalSection. This is my current working code with the pthread library.

```
T remove() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m_mutex);
    while (m_queue.size() == 0) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&m_condv, &m_mutex);
    }
    T item = m_queue.front();
    m_queue.pop_front();
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_mutex);
    return item;
}
```

Comment: Honestly, i'd use the [thread support library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) from C++11, which VC++2012 and later supports. Doing this with Windows primitives honestly isn't worth the hassle if you have to roll it yourself. If you can restrict your install-domain to Vista/Server2008 and later, you can use [Windows Condition Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682052(v=vs.85).aspx), making it significantly more straight forward.

Comment: consider WhozCraig's suggestion carefully. Rolling your own condition variable support on pre-Vista Win32 is not trival: http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/win32-cv-1.html

Comment: I am stuck to supporting MSVC 6.0 and MSVC 2010, so it is not an option. However, I am ok with using the pthread library, but wanted to make sure I wasn't missing some simple alternative. Which from your comments I am not.

Comment: Style note: Avoid testing for emptiness with `size() == 0`; not all containers offer O(1) `size()`, that's why there's an `empty()` - it's not [always] just a shortcut. Also, before I saw you can't use C++11, I converted your code to std::thread, see here: http://pastebin.com/aVzJL1ag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my attempt. This is not the best implementation of a conditional wait lock in win32, but I think it works.  It could use careful code review scrutiny.

One caveat - it doesn't necessarily guarantee ordered fairness since all the waiting threads may be initially blocked waiting for the event. The scheduler will resume all the threads at this point to continue running (up to the subsequent blocking EnterCriticalSection call), but not necessarily in the same order in which the threads arrived into the remove() call to begin with. This likely isn't a big deal for most app's with only a handful of threads, but it's something most threading frameworks guarantee.

Other caveat - for brevity, I'm leaving out the important steps of checking the return value from all of these Win32 APIs.

```
CRITICAL_SECTION m_cs;
HANDLE m_event;

void Init()
{
   InitializeCriticalSection(&m_cs);
   m_event = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL); // manual reset event
}

void UnInit()
{
    DeleteCriticalSection(&m_cs);
    CloseHandle(m_event);
    m_event = NULL;
}

T remove()
{
    T item;
    bool fGotItem = false;
    while (fGotItem == false)
    {
        // wait for event to be signaled
        WaitForSingleObject(m_event, INFINITE);

        // wait for mutex to become available
        EnterCriticalSection(&m_cs);

        // inside critical section
        {
            // try to deque something - it’s possible that the queue is empty because another 
            // thread pre-empted us and got the last item in the queue before us

            size_t queue_size = m_queue.size();

            if (queue_size == 1)
            {
               // the queue is about to go empty
               ResetEvent(m_event);
            }

            if (queue_size > 0)
            {
                fGotItem = true;
                item = m_queue.front();

                m_queue.pop();        
            }
        }

        LeaveCriticalSection(&m_cs);

    }

    return item;
}

void Add(T& item)
{
    // wait for critical section to become available
    EnterCriticalSection(&m_cs);

    // inside critical section
    {
        m_queue.push_back(item);

        SetEvent(m_event); // signal other threads that something is available
    }

    LeaveCriticalSection(&m_cs);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the best answer for me. Works on MSVC6.0 and 2012, Win7 and WinXp!

Comment: @uncletall - Just make sure you test it appropriately and do at least some amount of validation of return values the calls in Init and WaitForSingleObject calls. I didn't actually compile or test this code. I actually wrote it with a text editor on my **Mac-Mini** :)

Answer (score 3):

For pre-VC-2012 support, the best alternative is [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread.html) that supports conditional variables.

Comment: I guess it is time I learned Boost... but maybe later... plus Boost.Thread is still an additional dll which is what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: It's not in additional dll until you asked it to be there. By default (at least on Windows) it's compiled to a static lib. Yeah, it's still should be compiled but this takes 5 mins.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Didn't know that. Really have to find time to tame the Boost beast...

Answer (score 1):

Windows Vista introduced new native Win32 [Conditional Variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682052%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Slim Reader/Writer Lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa904937%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) primitives for exactly this type of scenario, for example:

Using a critical section:

```
CRITICAL_SECTION m_cs;
CONDITION_VARIABLE m_condv;

InitializeCriticalSection(&m_cs);
InitializeConditionVariable(&m_condv);

...

void add(T item)
{ 
    EnterCriticalSection(&m_cs);
    m_queue.push_back(item);
    LeaveCriticalSection(&m_cs);
    WakeConditionVariable(&m_condv);
}

T remove()
{ 
    EnterCriticalSection(&m_cs);
    while (m_queue.size() == 0)
        SleepConditionVariableCS(&m_condv, &m_cs, INFINITE);
    T item = m_queue.front();
    m_queue.pop_front();
    LeaveCriticalSection(&m_cs);
    return item;
}
```

Using a SRW lock:

```
SRWLOCK m_lock;
CONDITION_VARIABLE m_condv;

InitializeSRWLock(&m_lock);
InitializeConditionVariable(&m_condv);

...

void add(T item)
{ 
    AcquireSRWLockExclusive(&m_lock);
    m_queue.push_back(item);
    ReleaseSRWLockExclusive(&m_lock);
    WakeConditionVariable(&m_condv);
}

T remove()
{ 
    AcquireSRWLockExclusive(&m_lock);
    while (m_queue.size() == 0)
        SleepConditionVariableSRW(&m_condv, &m_lock, INFINITE, 0);
    T item = m_queue.front();
    m_queue.pop_front();
    ReleaseSRWLockExclusive(&m_lock);
    return item;
}
```

Comment: Unless the OP needs WinXP support, I'll favor this answer over the one I provided. I had forgotten about the SRW stuff.  Good answer!